# Should a new Collection be created upon Model.create()

Tags: express, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Am working with mongoose and have two models. The User model and the Service model, when a user logs in the method will `findOne()` user if one exists or `create()` a new user based on the what's passed in from `req.body`.

My Service Schema is like this:

```
const serviceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: 'contentEditor'
  },
  display: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Content Editor'
  },
  accessLevel: {
    type: Number,
    min: 0,
    max: 4,
    default: 4
  }
});
```

My User Schema is a bit bigger, I've removed some of the field/value pairs but the part where I embed the Service Schema looks like this:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Must have a email address'],
      trim: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    firstName: {
      type: String,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
    },
    services: {
        type: [serviceSchema],
        ref: 'Services',
        default: [serviceSchema],
    },
  },
);
```

When I hit the `/api/v1/login` endpoint a new user will be created with the Service document correctly but within the Mongoose database only a User collection exists. How do I make it so that both a Users collection and Services collection are created?

Edit: Below is the function that I create/find the user with when they login. When an existing User is found, by their email it will return that user if the user is not found then it will create a new one...

Both behaviours are as expected **including** adding the Services to the newly created User. What isn't expected is that only ONE collection is added to the DB.

```
const login = catchAsync(async ({ body: { email, password } }, res, next) => {
  if (!email || !password) {
    return next(new AppError('Please provide email and password', 400));
  }
  const { Success } = await webApi(email, password);
  const mongoUser = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (Success && mongoUser) {
    return createSendtoken(mongoUser, 200, res);
  }
  if (Success && !mongoUser) {
    const newUser = await User.create({ email });
    return createSendtoken(newUser, 201, res);
  }
  return next(new AppError('User not found', 404));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are making the serviceSchema a mongoose model.

```
const Services = mongoose.model('Service', serviceSchema)
```

You also have to save it using mongooses `model.save()` function

Comment: Apologies the schemas are both models already, I've only omitted that code to save space, I'll update the OP with the function which creates the User model. I assume that create calls `save()`?

Comment: I actually don't think that will create a separate collection. If you want another collection for your Service Schema, you will have to manually create and save one.

Comment: Yep, it's looking like that's the way in which it'll have to be done. Thanks